# plot from within a loop in R?

Tags: r, plot

Assum I have this:

```
     a <- 3:10
     for (i in seq_along(a))
     {
                  x <- a*i
     tiff("plottinh.tif", res = 300, width = 6000, height = 2000, units = "px") 
     par(mar=c(8, 5, 2.5, 3),mfrow=c(1,3), mgp=c(3.5, 1, 0))
     plot(x)
     dev.off()
     }
```

This will produce only one figure for the last `x`.

According to `mfrow=c(1,3)`, I should have 8 plots of x: first three in one panel then second three in one panel then the last two plots in one panel.

so finally I have

```
  first three plots of x  >>    plottinh1.tif 
  second three plots of x >>    plottinh2.tif
  last two plots of x    >>    plottinh3.tif
```

Any idea on this?

Comment: `par` and `dev.off` should be outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This would give you the required output.

```
a <- 3:10
tiff("plottinh.tif", res = 300, 
     width = 6000, height = 2000, 
     units = "px") 
par(mar=c(8, 5, 2.5, 3), mfrow=c(3,3), 
    mgp=c(3.5, 1, 0))
for (i in seq_along(a))
{
  x <- a*i
  plot(x)
}
dev.off()
```

There was a mistake in defining `mfrow` parameter, it should be `mfrow=c(3,3)` assuming you want the plot with three columned-subplots.

Comment: Thanks but there was no mistake. As i said in the question:I should have 8 plots of x: first three in one panel then second three in one panel then the last two plots in one panel

Comment: Yes, above code will give you that. With `mfrow=c(1,3)` you will see only `...the last two plots in one panel `. You could try the above code for seeing the result.

Comment: I meant three separate images not all on the same image.

Comment: That was not clear from your question. Can you please edit your question for clarity?